Integral identity for thermal states
Context:
In this paper, the authors establish a relationship between quantum Fisher information and the imaginary part of the dynamic susceptibility of a system.
To do so they utilize the identity:
$$2\int_{0}^{\infty}\tanh\left(\frac{\omega}{2T}\right)\delta(\omega+E_{\lambda^{´}}-E_{\lambda})d\omega= \tanh\left(\frac{E_{\lambda^{´}}-E_{\lambda}}{2T}\right)$$
Where $E_{\lambda}$ and $E_{\lambda^{´}}$ are energies of (different) states of a given system. They say this holds true for "a thermal state".
Now my question:
To my understanding the left hand side above should give $2\tanh\left(\frac{E_{\lambda}-E_{\lambda^{´}}}{2T}\right)$, given that $E_{\lambda}\gt E_{\lambda^{´}}$ or just 0 otherwise. Not only losing a factor of -2 but also some generality compared to the paper.
So what is the reasoning behind the identity given in the paper?

So you're questioning the loss of a factor of 2?
